# SQL Comparison on Aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

When I run the following SQL in ACCESS 2007

> Select Location,
>   COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) AS
>   TotalIBuildingsManaged From Apartments
>   Where COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) > 3 
>   Group By Location   Order By
>   COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) DESC;

I get the following error:

Cannot have aggregate function in where clause. How should I be forming this query to get all of the locations which have a count of ApartmentBuildings greater than 3?

Comment: If you'd use the Access query builder, it will write the appropriate SQL for you, and it would have used a HAVING clause instead of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `having` instead of `where`:

```
Select Location, COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) AS TotalIBuildingsManaged 
From Apartments 
Group By Location
Having COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) > 3  
Order By COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) DESC;
```

for more information [see this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/having-clause-HP001032238.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [HAVING](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/having-clause-HP001032238.aspx) clause

```
Select Location, COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) AS TotalIBuildingsManaged 
From Apartments 
Group By Location 
HAVING COUNT(ApartmentBuildings) > 3
```